# C++ Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm results in stack overflow

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I was working on a simple Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm and the code is below:

```
int main()
{

    const int n = 1000000;

    int sqrn = floor(sqrt(n));

    bool primes[n + 1] = { 0 }; // false means prime, true not prime

    primes[0] = true;
    primes[1] = true;

    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrn; i++){

        if (primes[i] == false) {
            int j = i + i;
            while (j<=n-1){
                primes[j] = true;
                j = j + i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My main question is that this code results in stack overflow error if I try to set the search array to greater than n=1000000. I am not sure if this is because a programming error or because of the program can not hold a boolean array larger than 10^6 entries? Any advice is appreciated.

Another minor question I have is whether setting the evaluation of the square root of n outside the for-loop statement improves execution speed.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `bool primes[n + 1] = { 0 };`, do:

```
std::vector<bool> primes(n+1);
```

This allocates non-stack space for enough primes, and initializes them all to `false`.

This version has another advantage in that the compiler may specialize it to use one bit per value, whereas your version used one byte per value.

A similar alternative that may have better performance (but is only possible when the size is known at compile-time) is

```
std::bitset<n+1> primes;
```

If you look up its documentation you may be able to improve your code's performance.

Comment: Thank you. The vector method seems to work well for larger n. Does bitset use the stack also?

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't appear to say whether `bitset` uses automatic allocation or free store allocation for its bits. It might be allowed to use automatic storage (aka. stack), so perhaps you should stick to the `vector`.

Comment: just curious is there a way to allocate vector in stack instead of heap ?

Comment: No, it would not be possible to resize the vector at runtime if vectors worked that way

Answer (score 2):

You are allocating the `primes` array on the stack. The stack only has a limited size (it's pretty big, but it's still limited). You can either:

- allocate your array in the global data area, or
- allocate your array on the heap with `new`

Answer (score 1):

The stack overflow is likely because your stack is not just under 1MB (or 1MB depending on your definition) in size. `bool` is usually 1 byte. Try allocating the primes array on the heap (using `new[]`) to avoid the stack size limitation. Remember to release the array with `delete[]`.

Also the primality of `n` will be incorrect from this algorithm. You want to change `j<=n-1` to `j<=n`.

Comment: In general how much space is available on the stack? Does this depend on system the code is running on?

Comment: @virtore Yes, it depends very much on your C++ runtime. It can be extended in a number of ways, depending on platform. For example, Win32 programs can set the stack size of a new thread when the thread is created with [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx), and when using POSIX threads on Linux with [pthread_attr_setstacksize](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Stack). However I would just allocate large amounts of memory on the heap; allocating such a large stack is wasteful and makes it harder for the memory to be reclaimed.